# Not executing setState inside .map() unless i print it

Tags: flutter, dart

so when I tried without the print the code doesn't execute, but when the print is included the code runs 'normally', is there another way of coding this without using print?

Not Working

```
x.map((v) {
    setState(() {
        _userList.add(v.data['name']);
    });
});
```

Working

```
print(x.map((v) {
    setState(() {
        _userList.add(v.data['name']);
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `x` is a `List`, then this is expected behaviour. `map` returns a *lazy iterable*. What this means is that nothing is actually executed until the mapped list is iterated. From the [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/map.html):

> This method returns a view of the mapped elements. As long as the returned Iterable is not iterated over, the supplied function f will not be invoked.

This is why it *is* working when you print - the print function needs to iterate over the items, and so setState is called.

The `map` method is usually used to transform each item in a list in some way. If you want to execute something for each item in the list, consider using the [`forEach`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/forEach.html) method instead:

```dart
x.forEach((v) {
    setState(() {
        _userList.add(v.data['name']);
    });
});
```

Comment: [Or just use a `for` loop](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal).

Comment: Yep, I went with `forEach` because it was the minimal code change from the original question.